# Tastypie tests fail with TransactionManagementError

Tags: tastypie

Running the django-tastypie tests fails with lots of TransactionManagementErrors.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but having trouble figuring out what it is.

I followed these directions on a cloned repository with no changes.

https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/604e4ac97046773625c99ae43dd1c1df1b4d39af/docs/index.rst#running-the-tests

How do I get the tests working?

```
$ tox -e py27-dj18
py27-dj18 develop-inst-nodeps: /home/aaron/django-tastypie
py27-dj18 installed: biplist==1.0.1,coverage==4.2,defusedxml==0.4.1,Django==1.8.17,django-oauth-plus==2.2.9,-e git+git@github.com:aaronelliotross/django-tastypie.git@29eae9123152cd9e96090b63916fa501b2ef37a3#egg=django_tastypie,httplib2==0.9.2,lxml==3.6.4,mock==1.0.1,oauth2==1.9.0.post1,pysqlite==2.7.0,python-dateutil==2.6.0,python-digest==1.7,python-mimeparse==1.6.0,pytz==2013b0,PyYAML==3.12,six==1.10.0
py27-dj18 runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='1556702699'
py27-dj18 runtests: commands[0] | /home/aaron/django-tastypie/.tox/py27-dj18/bin/coverage run --append --source=tastypie,tests /home/aaron/django-tastypie/.tox/py27-dj18/bin/django-admin.py test -p * core.tests --settings=settings_core
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..E..E..EE..............E..E.E....................................................E.EEEE................................................EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE..EEEEEE.........E..EEE.EEE.EEEEE.E.EEEEEE...........................................................E........EEEEEEEE.EEE..E.EEEE.....
======================================================================
```

.. snip ...

---

Ran 372 tests in 2.014s

FAILED (errors=155)